# How is $k[x,y]/(y^2) \to k[x,y,z]/(z^2, xz-y)$ an integral extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Any polynomial in $k[x,y,z]/(z^2, xz-y)$ can be written as
$$c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_3z+c_4x^2+c_5xy+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+\cdots + dx^n+ex^{n-1}y.$$

From this, we can see that $k[x,y]/(y^2) \to k[x,y,z]/(z^2, xz-y)$ is injective.

However, I don't see how it is integral.

Which polynomial in $\frac{k[x,y]}{(y^2)}[t]$ is satisfied by $c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_3z+c_4x^2+c_5xy+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+\cdots + dx^n+ex^{n-1}y$?

Comment: It might be easier to show that the generators $x,y,z$ are integral. Alternatively note that the map is finite (because the target is already as a $k[x]$-module f.g.)

Comment: @leoli1 We know $x$ and $y$ are integral over  $k[x,y]/(y^2)$, trivially. And $z$ satisfies the polynomial $t^2$.  However, why this is sufficient to guarantee every element is integral?

Comment: In general if $S/R$ is a ring extension and $\alpha\in S$ is integral over $R$, then $S[\alpha]$ is integral over $R$. Thus it suffices to test integrality of a ring on the generators over the base ring. In this case $x,y,z$ generate the ring $k[x,y,z]/(z^2,xz-y)$ over $k[x,y]/(y^2)$ (actually $z$ would already suffice I guess)

Answer (score 1):

Since $$(c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_3z+c_4x^2+c_5xy+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+\cdots + dx^n+ex^{n-1}y)-(c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_4x^2+c_5xy+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+\cdots + dx^n+ex^{n-1}y)=c_3z$$ and $(c_3 z)^2 \equiv 0$ in $k[x,y,z]/(z^2, xz-y)$, then the monic polynomial
$$(t-c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_4x^2+c_5xy+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+\cdots + dx^n+ex^{n-1}y)^2$$
in $\frac{k[x,y]}{(y^2)}[t]$ has root $c_0+c_1x+c_2y+c_3z+c_4x^2+c_5xy+c_6x^3+c_7x^2y+\cdots + dx^n+ex^{n-1}y$.